Why $\omega|_S\in\Omega^1(S,\mathfrak{g})$?
Let $S$ be a $G$-structure on $M$ and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $M$ compatible with $S$, i.e. the parallel transport preserves $S$.
Consider now the induced principal bundle connection on $Fr(TM)$ represented by the connection form
$$\omega\in\Omega^1(Fr(TM),\mathfrak{gl}_r).$$
This connection form is defined as follows, let's take a tanget vector
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\ \varepsilon(t)\in T_{\varepsilon(0)}Fr(TM),$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a smooth curve
$$\varepsilon:[-1,1]\to Fr(TM),\ \ \ \varepsilon(t)=(\varepsilon_1(t),\dots,\varepsilon_r(t)).$$
Let's consider the derivative of path of $\varepsilon_j$:
$$\frac{\nabla \varepsilon_j}{dt}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^ra_j^i(t)\varepsilon_i(t),$$
that give rise to the matrix
$$(a_j^i(t))_{i,j}\in \mathfrak{gl}_r.$$
We then define $\omega$:
$$\omega_{\varepsilon(0)}\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\ \varepsilon(t)\right):=(a_j^i(t))_{i,j}.$$
I wanna show that $\omega$ is such that, when restricted to vectors tangent to $S$, it takes values in $\mathfrak{g}$ (the Lie algebra of $G$), i.e.:
$$\omega|_S\in\Omega^1(S,\mathfrak{g}).$$
Any tips?

What do $\left.\omega\right|_S$ and $\Omega^1(S,\mathfrak{g})$ mean if $S$ is a $G$-structure on $M$?

@Deane thanks for your comment, I tried to better explain the notation.

Let  $f = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$ be a $G$-frame on a neighborhood of $p \in M$.
Let $\epsilon: (-1,1) \rightarrow M$ be a curve such that $\epsilon(0)=p$, and denote $v = \epsilon'(0) \in T_pM$.
Let $\hat{f} = (\hat{f}_1, \dots, \hat{f}_n)$ be the parallel translation of $f(p)$ along the curve $\epsilon$. If $\nabla$ is compatible with $S$, then
$$
\hat{f}(t) \in S.
$$
On the other hand, there exists $g: (-1,1)\rightarrow G$ such that
$$
\hat{f}_k = f_jg^j_k
$$
along $\epsilon$. Differentiate this and write in terms of the connection $1$-forms for $f$.

@Deane thank you!
